# Just Dance 2021: How much content is offered in "Kids Mode"?

Tags: nintendo-switch, just-dance-series

I'm interested in Just Dance 2021 for Switch, but I don't know much about it. I read that there's a "Kids Mode". How much different is it from the normal mode? How much of the game can actually be enjoyed in this mode?

[Here's](https://support.ubisoft.com/en-GB/Article/000080322/Modo-Kids-en-Just-Dance-2021) what Ubisoft has to say about it:

> To create a safe space for children to have fun and enjoy dancing, we
> included Kids Mode in Just Dance 2020!
>
> In this mode, you will find adapted and new songs for kids. We have
> also developed new choreography, with the help of kids’ development
> experts, to encourage healthy movement.

So... like what percent of the game does that comprise?

Also, how kid-unfriendly is the game when it's not in Kids Mode? I've sort of got a sense of what to expect from [these reviews](https://www.commonsensemedia.org/game-reviews/just-dance-2021/user-reviews/adult), but without knowing more I feel like it's a gamble.

I guess both of those questions are two aspects of the single question: how much kid-friendly content are you getting when you buy the game?

Comment: So, this is where I'd encourage you to leverage the ESRB/PEGI/Ratings board of your locale's understanding of the ratings however, in the US: ESRB has rated the title E for Everyone (not E10+), stating "mild lyrics" as the cause. In my experience of OTHER JD titles, they use the "clean" songs which alter the naughty words to lighter or completely skip them. That said, NOT counting the "JD Unlimited" monthly membership, Kids mode may be taking this one step further to evaluate the content of the song (Let's just say WAP likely isn't making the cut) to ensure it's "kid friendly"

Comment: Sample of Kids Mode: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5EolDB0Aw0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [*Kids Mode Songs*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hyE-PApMDKg)

- Dance Of The Mirlitons – The Just Dance Orchestra (Kids Mode)
- Flying Carpet – Persian Nights (Kids Mode)
- Get On The Fire Truck – The Step Brigade (Kids Mode)
- Here Comes The Spy – The Step Brigade (Kids Mode)
- Let’s Save Our Planet – The Sunlight Shakers (Kids Mode)
- Rock N Roll Princess – Fast Forward Highway (Kids Mode)
- Space Cat – Equinox Stars (Kids Mode)
- The Color Lab – Dancing Bros. (Kids Mode)

### how unkid-friendly are the songs? (too opininated, so here's the songlist.)

### *Songlist*

- Adore You – Harry Styles
- Alexandrie Alexandra – Jerôme Francis
- All The Good Girls Go To Hell – Billie Eilish
- Bailando – Paradisio Ft. DJ Patrick Samoy
- Blinding Lights – The Weeknd
- Boy, You Can Keep It – Alex Newell
- Buscando – Good Times Ahead, Jenn Morel
- Dance Monkey – Tones & I
- Dibby Dibby Sound – DJ Fresh & Jay Fay Ft. Ms Dyanmite
- Don’t Start Now – Dua Lipa
- FEEL SPECIAL – TWICE
- Georgia – Tiggs Da Author
- Get Get Down – Paul Johnson
- Heat Seeker – DREAMERS
- Ice Cream – Blackpink & Selena Gomez
- In The Navy – The Sunlight Shakers
- Joone Khodet – Black Cats
- Juice – Lizzo
- Kick It – NCT 127
- Kulitaka – Toño Roasario
- Lacrimosa – Apashe
- Magenta Riddim – DJ Snake
- Paca Dance – The Just Dance Band
- Que Tire Pa’ ‘Lante – Daddy Yankee
- Rain On Me – Lady Gaga & Ariana Grande
- Rare – Selena Gomez
- Runaway (U & I) – Galantis
- Samba De Janeiro – Ultraclub 90
- Say So – Doja Cat
- Señorita – Shawn Mendes & Camilla Cabello
- Temperature – Sean Paul
- The Other Side – SZA & Justin Timberlake
- The Weekend – Michael Gray
- Till The World Ends – The Girly Team
- U.S.A – Da Pump
- Uno – Little Big
- Volar – Lele Pons ft. Susan Diaz and Victor Cardenas
- Without Me – Eminem
- Yameen Yasar – DJ Absi
- YO LE LLEGO – J Balvin, Bad Bunny
- You’ve Got A Friend In Me – Disney Pixar’s Toy Story
- Zenit – ONUKA

### *Alternates Version*

- Blinding Lights – The Weeknd (Extreme Version)
- Buscando – Good Times Ahead, Jenn Morel (Extreme Version)
- Don’t Start Now – Dua Lipa (Extreme Version)
- FEEL SPECIAL – TWICE (Extreme Version)
- Juice – Lizzo (Yummy Version)
- Kick It – NCT 127 (Extreme Version)
- Rare – Selena Gomez (Fairytale Version)
- Samba De Janeiro – Ultraclub 90 (Samba Version)
- Temperature – Sean Paul (Extreme Version)
- Till The World Ends – The Girly Team (Extreme Version)
- Without Me – Eminem (Extreme Version)
- Yameen Yasar – DJ Absi (Extreme Version)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to list all the tracks! While there are many I'm not familiar with, there are definitely some I am familiar with that should *not* be heard by young audiences. How on Earth does "Without Me" get an Everyone rating?! For reference, [here are the lyrics](https://genius.com/Eminem-without-me-lyrics). A great track for those in their late teens and older maybe, and one that I personally like, but... not for "everyone". Without knowing how much of the content has been altered to be suitable for young audiences, it's sort of impossible to know whether it's okay.

Comment: Still, I'm accepting your answer because it answered my question. The answer is: it's impossible to know how clean the "clean" versions are without extensively researching the clean version of EACH included track. As a result, it's best to just skip this title for young audiences. Thank you. (PS I agree "how kid-unfriendly" is too opinionated, and I don't expect someone else to judge that for me, but I has just hoping for a way to get the info I needed to judge for myself.)

Comment: yeah, it's very subjective.